# Google scripts If function wont call during iteration

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

My sheet has a Vlookup which checks if the name exists, and if it does not, produces an error message. The following code is designed to check if each cell contains the error message, and if it does flag it to the user by appending onto two arrays. One which contains the incorrect name, and one which contains the row of the error. I know, via Logger.log(), that the iteration works but for some reason the IF statement is not being called in the function.

```js
function nameCheck(){
  var numEmail = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Validations').getRange('D2').getValue();
  Logger.log(numEmail)
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Input');
   var startRow = 1;
  var numRows = numEmail
  var invalid = []
  var rowWithError = []
  var dataRange = ss.getRange(startRow, 9, numRows, 9);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i in data){
    var row = data[i];
    Logger.log(row)
      if (row == "Please Check Name, , , , , , , ,  ") {
        var wrongName = ss.getRange('A' + row)
        var invalid = invalid.push(wrongName)
        var rowWithError = rowWithError.push(row[i])
    }
      else{}
  } 
  if (invalid.length != 0){
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
        ui.alert(
          "The sheet had detected an invalid Name - '" + invalid + "', please check row " + rowWithError + " and try again.",)
  }
  else{}
}
```

Any help would be great, as I am new to this

Comment: What is `"Please Check Name, , , , , , , ,  "` of `if (row == "Please Check Name, , , , , , , ,  ") {`?

Comment: It is the output of the formula where the name is not recognised by the Vlookup. I am not sure why the text is followed by ,,,,,,. Regardless of this statement, the IF part does not run

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, `row` is `"Please Check Name, , , , , , , ,  "`. So at `ss.getRange('A' + row)`, I think that the A1Notation is `APlease Check Name, , , , , , , ,  `. How about this? If I misunderstood your replying, I apologize.

Comment: Hello - thank you for having a look. I am a bit confused by your response. Please could you try amending the code snippet and replying? The issue is that the IF statement is not called. Also doesn't the double == compare values, not rewrite the variable Sorry

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that the reason that you confused is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. And, I noticed that I misunderstood your situation, and I thought that in this case, when the explanation is shown, it might be useful. So I posted it as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question again, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `data` is retrieved from the range of `ss.getRange(startRow, 9, numRows, 9)`, and `row` is `data[i]` which is 2 dimensional array. In this case, `row` is one dimensional array which has 9 elements. By this, `if (row == "Please Check Name, , , , , , , ,  ") {` is always false. So `invalid.length` is always `0`. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue.
- From your `"Please Check Name, , , , , , , ,  "` of `if (row == "Please Check Name, , , , , , , ,  ") {`, I thought that the value might be the text joined cell values of the row.
- `push` returns the array length. So `var invalid = invalid.push(wrongName)` and `var rowWithError = rowWithError.push(row[i])` are run, `invalid` and `rowWithError` are the array length.
- I think that `var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();` can be declared one time.

If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

From:

```
for (var i in data){
  var row = data[i];
  Logger.log(row)
    if (row == "Please Check Name, , , , , , , ,  ") {
      var wrongName = ss.getRange('A' + row)
      var invalid = invalid.push(wrongName)
      var rowWithError = rowWithError.push(row[i])
  }
    else{}
} 
if (invalid.length != 0){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
      ui.alert(
        "The sheet had detected an invalid Name - '" + invalid + "', please check row " + rowWithError + " and try again.",)
}
else{}
```

To:

```
data.forEach((row, i) => {
  if (row.join(",") == "Please Check Name, , , , , , , ,  ") {
    var wrongName = ss.getRange('A' + (i + 1)).getValue();
    invalid.push(wrongName);
    rowWithError.push(row);  // or rowWithError.push(row.join(","))
  }
  if (invalid.length != 0){
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.alert(
    "The sheet had detected an invalid Name - '" + invalid.pop() + "', please check row " + rowWithError.pop() + " and try again.",)
  }
});
```

#### Note:

- From your question, I cannot understand about your actual Spreadsheet. So when above proposed modification was not the direct solution, can you provide your sample Spreadsheet for replicating your issue, and provide the detail of your goal? By this, I would like to confirm it.
- Of course, in your case, I think that the string variable can be also used instead of the array as follows.

  ```
    var invalid = "";
    var rowWithError = "";
    data.forEach((row, i) => {
      if (row.join(",") == "Please Check Name, , , , , , , ,  ") {
        var wrongName = ss.getRange('A' + (i + 1)).getValue();
        invalid = wrongName;
        rowWithError = row.join(",");
      }
      if (invalid.length != 0){
        var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
        ui.alert(
        "The sheet had detected an invalid Name - '" + invalid + "', please check row " + rowWithError + " and try again.",)
      }
    });
  ```

#### References:

- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)